# Automating scp upload without password

Tags: python, ssh-keys, pexpect, apscheduler, beagleboneblack

I am working on having `APScheduler` upload a data file periodically using `pexepect.run('scp ...')`.

The `scp` command works fine from the command line without password authentication (keys have been shared).

However, when running in a python script on `Beaglebone Black` (started from a remote machine using pexpect), `scp` fails because `blackbear` (which replaces `openssh` on the `BBB`) doesn't load the private key properly.

When I add `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, then I get an error from `/usr/bin/dbclient: Exited: String too long`

`dbclient` is part of `blackbear` and this appears to be bug. When trying to convert my private key using `dropbearconvert openssh dropbear id_rsa id_rsa.db`, I get the error: `Error: Ciphers other than DES-EDE3-CBC not supported`. I tried to install `openssh`, but this didn't work due to a conflict with `blackbear`.

Just before I give up on `Angstrom` and go to `Ubuntu`, are there any suggestions?

I have already added a lot to `Angstrom` so changing operating systems at this time is painful.

Thanks.

Bit_Pusher

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, I found I could schedule pulling from the server using APScheduler and pexpect.run along with scp. This is less than ideal, as I prefer to have the always running processes on the beaglebones, rather than the server, but it will suffice until I can schedule enough time to switch to Ubuntu. Still, if anyone has suggestions on how to get blackbear working, I would much like to hear them. Bit_Pusher